# Environment Variable holds the previous values even after being set on Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: linux, bash, ubuntu

I am working on a Linux machine installed on Oracle VirtualBox. Environment details are like below:

- Oracle VirtualBox: version: 6.1
- Operating System Ubuntu Version: 20.04

I created a  custom.sh file in `/etc/profile.d`. The content of custom.sh is like below:

```
export CUSTOM_VAR=value1
```

Then I sourced with the command: `source /etc/profile` and verified with `echo $CUSTOM_VAR`.
Everything work as it should.

After I modified the custom.sh file by changing the value to the variable like this:  `export CUSTOM_VAR=value2` and source it. It works fine in the terminal.

I am having a problem that every time I open a new terminal `echo $CUSTOM_VAR` it prints the old value, not the new one.

I run the commands below to verify if the variable is declared elsewhere:

- `sudo grep -r CUSTOM_VAR /etc/*`, Result is like below:

  `/etc/profile.d/custom.sh:export CUSTOM_VAR=value2`
- `sudo grep -r CUSTOM_VAR ~/.*`  , Result is like empty.

I will appreciate any guide towards solving this issue.

Regards,

Rando.

Update.....................

I have checked all the files below :

- /etc/environment
- /etc/env.d/*
- /etc/profile
- /etc/profile.d/*
- /etc/bashrc, /etc/bash.bashrc
- /.bash_profile
- /.bashrc
- /.profile

Comment: What about .bashrc ? cd ~ && vi .bashrc

Comment: After running the source command I get the correct value.  It is not a typo.

Comment: Start a new X session.

Comment: `/etc/profile` is executed only by login shells.

Comment: I restarted the machine and seems to have fixed the issue. I think you might be right regarding /etc/profile is executed only for login or where it starts.